# Problem having on Java; replace the character

Tags: java, string, replace

```
public static int conversion(int n) {

    String str = Integer.toString(n);    //int to string
    String str1= str.replace('0', '5'); //replace the character in string
    int result1 = Integer.parseInt(str1); //string to int

    int result = result1;

    return result;


}
```

I'm trying to replace the character from '0' to '5'.
The current code works, but only when there is no '0' at the front.

example: '50005' -> '55555' (o) ; '00005000' -> '5555' (x) <-front '0' didn't change

What should I add or know to fix this error?

Comment: Because `555` and `00000555` are the *same* number, according to maths.

Comment: `Integer.toString` will never return you a string with leading zeros. The `int` literal `00005000` is actually in octal representation and will be interpreted as `2560` -> `conversion(00005000)` is equal to `conversion(2560)` and will return `2565`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leading zeroes on ints are ignored in the conversion process.

```
String str = "0000123";
int n = Integer.valueOf(str);
System.out.println(str);
System.out.println(n);
```

Prints

```
0000123
123
```

If you prefix a 0 to an int, it treats it as an octal value and ignores the zeros.

```
int octalVal = 000031;
System.out.println(octalVal);
String decimalStringVal = Integer.toString(octalVal);
System.out.println(decimalStringVal);
```

Prints

```
25
25
```